# Create Javascript for browser client from various typescripts files (modules) into a separated namespaces

Tags: typescript, browser, gulp, namespaces, browserify

I'm coding a JS app for browser client. The source code is in Typescript in separated files. And the outcome for the browser MUST be (system requirements) two js files.

The source file structure  and code files (src/client), is as follow:

```
/project
    /assets
        /js
            jquery.js
/core
    /ts
        app.ts
        basics.ts
        helper.ts
/extended
    /module1
        /ts
            some1_1.ts
            some1_2.ts
    /module2
        /ts
            some2_1.ts
            some2_2.ts
```

The output, as JS files, goes as follows:

```
/dist
    /public
        /js
            jquery.js
            bundleCore.js  
            bundleExtended.js
```

So, the html file is something like this

```
<html>
    <body>
        ...
        <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/bundleCore.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/bundleExtended.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I actually use a task runner (gulp) in order to join and compile all ts files from /core/* into buldleCore.js, and all from /extended/* into bundleExtended.js

I also use browserify to make TS code browser compatible.

With gulp I transpile, join and uglify the files of /core folder in one file, and those in /extended folder in the other file. That gets the two files within dist/public/js

My tsconfig, is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "files": [
    "./node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false  
}
```

The problem: two diferents scopes are created in the global scope.
A scope for "bundleCore.js" and other for "bundleExtended.js", both separated, and not possible to interact from each other.
Like:

```
(function()
    //here the bundleExtended code
)();

(function()
    //here the bundleCore code
)();
```

I'd like to be able to keep both in the global scope (in separated namespaces by source file) or in a separated namespaces, so I can reach and access to thier scopes. An example:

```
// on bundleCore
    var MyApp = (function(...));
    var MyBasics = (function (...));
    var MyHelper = (function(...));

// on bundleExtended
    var MyModule1 = (function(){
        ...
        MyBasics.anyFunction(); //acces by namespace
        var oneHelper = new MyHelper(); //create an instance class
        oneHelper.anyMethod();
        ...
    })();
```

Or an alternatively:

```
// From bundleCore
    var MyCore = (function(...//bundleCore namespaces here));

// From bundleExtended
    var MyModules = (function(){
        ...
        MyCore.MyBasics.anyFunction(); //access by namespace
        var oneHelper = new MyCore.MyHelper(); //create an instance class
        oneHelper.anyMethod();
        ...
    })();
```

So, the question is:
Is there any way to achive that? What would be the best way? Do i need change the scenario, the tools or tech used for?

Your responses are welcome, thanks a lot

PD: I'm so sorry for my English, I hope you can understood me